# Force Modelling in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, collada, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My question is that when we import cad model of a specific object, such as wing, and move it in gazebo environment, then lift and drag force on the wing are applied on the object according to profile of wing or we need to model these forces separately and cad model is only for asthetics?

Thanks in Advance !!

Gazebo : 7.13.1
Ubuntu : 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20228/force-modelling-in-gazebo-?/) by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

*Short Answer:*
Gazebo natively does not have CFD to simulate lift and drag. In order to simulate those forces, you would need to create/use a Plugin.

*Long Answer:*
Check out the [LiftDragPlugin Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=aerodynamics&cat=plugins) as well as its [source code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/LiftDragPlugin.cc) for hints on how you might simulate lift and drag using the CAD Model - to my knowledge, the LiftDragPlugin does not use the 3D model to calculate those forces.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1